# Table View is not populating after query (PFQuery)

Tags: ios, objective-c, swift, parse-platform

I can't seem to get this to work. I have an array `users` that should hold all of the users saved in the Parse database. In the query, users is filled with PFUsers from parse. For example if I do `println(self.users)` then it shows all the users from the database correctly. However, it doesn't fill the table with them and if I do the same `println(self.users)` in any of the table functions, it shows as an empty array. Furthermore, if I fill the array initially with users = ["X',"Y", "Z"] then the query removes those values and inserts users from Parse but then the table puts in the initial X,Y and Z values. This is driving me crazy.

```
import UIKit

class receivers: UIViewController, UITableViewDelegate, UITableViewDataSource {

    @IBOutlet var tableView: UITableView!

    var users = [""]

    override func viewDidLoad() {
        super.viewDidLoad()

        var query = PFUser.query()

        query.findObjectsInBackgroundWithBlock({ (objects: [AnyObject]!, error: NSError!) -> Void in

            self.users.removeAll(keepCapacity: true)
            for object in objects {

                var user:PFUser = object as PFUser

                if user.username != PFUser.currentUser().username {

                    self.users.append(user.username)

                }

            }



        })

    }


    override func didReceiveMemoryWarning() {
        super.didReceiveMemoryWarning()
        // Dispose of any resources that can be recreated.
    }

    func numberOfSectionsInTableView(tableView: UITableView) -> Int {

        return 1
    }



    func tableView(tableView: UITableView, numberOfRowsInSection section: Int) -> Int {

        return users.count
    }


    func tableView(tableView: UITableView, cellForRowAtIndexPath indexPath: NSIndexPath) -> UITableViewCell {

        var cell:UITableViewCell = self.tableView.dequeueReusableCellWithIdentifier("cell") as UITableViewCell
        cell.textLabel?.text = users[indexPath.row]
        return cell
    }

}
```

Comment: Did you run self.tableview.reloadData() after load all the results into your array?

Comment: @jsetting32 - sure looks like reloadData is missing.  Also double check that the posted class is set as the tableview's datasource.

Comment: @jsetting32 wow that was it! thanks! I am new to iOS and didn't realize that reloadData had to happen if this was occurring in viewDidLoad

Comment: No problem. It happens to all of us

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You need to call `self.tableView.reloadData()` once you load all your objects into the array your tableView is referencing.

Happy coding!